# Loop through range and find empty cells

Tags: excel, vba, is-empty

I have a problem with the following code. I would like it to loop through a range (AK2 until end of data) and then any time it finds an empty cell it changes its value to Account receivable. Its not doing it, I also dont get any error notification. My guess is that I´m doing something wrong with  setting the variables:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Leere()

Dim rng As range
Dim rcell As range
Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set rng = WS.range("AK2", range("AK2").End(xlDown))

For Each rcell In rng
    If rcell.Value = " " Then
            rcell.Value = "Accounts Receivable"
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To find a blank do .value = "" rather than .value = " " (Take out the space)

Comment: Wow it was only that! Thanks

Comment: How would it would it work with isempty(rcell)?

Comment: Do you mean a **truly blank cell** or a cell that contains a **zero-length string** ? If the former then you should be using `Set rng = WS.range("AK2", WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp))` . The `xlDown` you are currently using is going top stop at the first truly blank cell.

Comment: You'd also be better off using `Set rng = ws.range("AK2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp))`

Comment: You are right, I need it to replace all zero-lenght string cells. However, I tried using this code and it is not working. Meanwhile excel is still replacing the blank cells from my original code...

Answer (score 2):

use `SpecialCells()`

```
With ws
    .Range("AK2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "Accounts Receivable"
End With
```

Comment: as a side note for others, `SpecialCells` results in error if no cells found but an optional `On Error Resume Next` can be used to ignore those cases

Comment: @Slai, fine addition. Thanks

Comment: @Urumita, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace the empty (no formula) cells with something like this:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set rng = ws.Range("AK2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp))

rng.Replace "", "Accounts Receivable", xlWhole
```

Another non-VBA option can be Conditional Formatting for blank cells. The cell values will still be blank, but the displayed text change will be dynamic.